# git hook for git stash apply?

Tags: git, githooks

Is there a git hook that gets applied after I run `git stash apply`? If so, what is it? More generically, is there a single commit hook that gets run after a merge,rebase,stash, etc. Basically any time a file changes due to a git operation. In lieu of a single hook, I'd accept a list of hooks for the following: post merge, post rebase, post checkout, post stash apply.

Comment: There is not; but `git stash` is a shell script, so you could easily modify it to add your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like there is one for `git stash apply`. Most tend to occur on actual commits, pushes, or updates..not to changes in the working tree.  This list may help:

- `git merge` : [post-merge](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html#_post_merge)
- `git rebase` : [post-rewrite](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html#_post_rewrite) (also runs on `git commit --amend`)
- `git checkout` : [post-checkout](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html#_post_checkout)

Source: [githooks(5)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html#_post_checkout)

Comment: I just tried a `git stash apply` with a `post-merge` hook (since there was a chance that `git-stash` ran by applying a merge).  No luck though.