# Can I disable the git stash?

Tags: git, git-stash

I would rather make temporary commits than use the git stash.  More importantly, I would prefer my colleauges with less experience with git avoid the stash.

Is there a way to disable the git stash so that commands that interact with it terminate with an error?

EDIT: Thanks for the answers suggesting what I can do instead, but what I am really looking for is a "yes" or "no" answer, if possible with some justification, to the literal question.

Comment: I was thinking maybe there would be a hook you could use but it doesn't look like there is one. Maybe alias over it with an `echo no stashing allowed` command?

Comment: I think the only way to do this would be via some kind of hook, but [that doesn't appear to be possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117814/git-hook-for-git-stash-apply?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).  By the way, `git stash` works under the hood by making commits of its own.

Comment: Perhaps the best way to deal with this is just a wrapper script

Comment: please read this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538774/is-it-possible-to-override-git-command-by-git-alias

Comment: By the way, why do you dislike git stash?  I can not see any demerits of git stash comparing with  temporary commits.

Comment: @gzh I don't want two different interfaces to essentially exactly the same thing.

Comment: @TomEllis, git-commit and git-stash are not the same thing, a temporary commit will change your commit history graph, but git-stash won't. If you run `git log --graph  --oneline --all`, you will know what I mean.

Comment: @gzh They're not *exactly* the same thing but they are similar enough that I would prefer to be able to disable the stash, for simplicity of the user experience.

Answer (score 2):

Replace it with a script:

```
cd /usr/lib/git-core
mv git-stash git-stash.backup
echo "#!/bin/sh
echo git stash is disabled, please commit your changes" > git-stash
chmod a+rx git-stash
```

Answer (score 1):

I once answered a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48751491/prevent-git-stash-with-no-additional-arguments-from-running/48752733#48752733).

In your case, the function could be:

```
function git () {
    if [ "$1" = "stash" ];then
        echo '"git stash" is disabled, try "git commit" instead'
        exit 1
    else
        command git $@
    fi
}
```

But this function is not robust at all. It can prevent commands starting with `git stash`, but you can easily bypass it with a command like `git '' stash` or `git --git-dir=foo.git stash`. How to test if the command is essentially `git stash` is another problem. Besides, the function can't affect Git plugins in other tools. And I don't think this solution gives a good direction. Ideally Git should have a switch to enable/disable some of its sub-commands but I'm afraid it's another big problem.

If I get it right, the problem is that you want your less experienced colleagues to avoid `git stash` so that they would make fewer troubles. It's unfair. It would be nice, if you, as an experienced Git user, take responsibility for training them how to use `git stash` and its sub-commands properly. Show them the power and beauty of git commands. After all, `git stash` is not too hard to grasp. They are programmers. They can learn.

Believe me, for less experienced Git users who know little about Git internals, replacing `git stash` with `git commit` would be a disaster. They will definitely push needless commits and haunt you with a lot of questions.

Comment: great answer but you may consider nixing that `exit 1`, I think it's going to cause readers to accidentally exit from shells/terminals. Function should log and terminate safely without it.