# includeIf with branches in git

Tags: git, configuration, branch

Did someone manage to configure git to use something like

```
[includeIf "onbranch:feature/"]
   path = ~/.features.gitconfig
```

I am attaching a tar.gz with a docker's container. You can `docker import` it to be able to see the configuration that I have problems running with.

[Download docker](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fTRp05J3rhlNf1IeT8hdxyDv_H5TUfY6/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: To supplement previous post. I tried to test it by creating a branch called `feature/test`. According to git docs, a condition ending with `/` (forward slash) actually is `/**`. That said, IMHO, being on a branch `feature/test` should activate the configuration posted above.

Comment: Make sure the Git version you're using is recent: the includeIf and some of its fancier things don't exist or don't work in some Git versions that are still pretty commonly used. Otherwise, this does look like it should work, yes.

Comment: honestly...why haven't I thought about it :).

Comment: bumping from `2.17` to `2.25` does the trick. All you gotta do is `add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa`

Comment: @torek would you mind answering in a regular way so that I can vote up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're on Git version 2.23 or later:

- Git 2.13 added the overall `includeIf` idea; but
- Git 2.23 is where branch conditionals (`includeIf.onbranch:...`) first appeared.

(Git 2.22 fixed `**` operation in these conditionals, but obviously branch conditionals are required in the first place, so there's no issue there.)